# How to use a beamer template style in a standard article document

Tags: beamer, formatting, templates, document-classes

I'm trying to create a report which has some more 'modern' (less academic)
styling approaches. Some of the templates that I think could be suitable are
created for Beamer.

I'm wondering if it's possible to adapt a beamer theme to use with a standard LaTeX a4
document?

For example, elements from this theme look good : https://github.com/matze/mtheme

But I don't know how I can use this them in a standard file. So if have some
`\documentclass[12pt]{article}`, how can I use the styling from a beamer theme such as
https://github.com/matze/mtheme

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want something like this:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a4paper,]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}           % Use metropolis theme
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Centre for Modern Beamer Themes}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not really - but it might be a reasonable jumping off point for further styling as i was unable to find much that wasn't very academic looking for standard latex documents.

Comment: Keep in mind that by using beamer if you use a frame you will possibly need to load it with the option `[allowframebreaks]` Also, I don't suggest this way... but creating your own style instead (or transfer some things you really like in your own template).

Comment: Well the last thing you mentioned would be the crux of this question I suppose - how would I go about transferring something from a beamer template for use in a standard document? For example - if i like the styling of the 'first frame' bar, how would I extract that? If I could see that then I could do the rest and apply that to other templates as well

Comment: @baxx ... I am afraid that this is easier to create this from scratch than to extract it from beamer.... For beamer this is a kind of default layout and sure it is easier to define something like this from scratch than extracting from such a different documentclass. (but didn't even tried to find it... For me it is not something meaningful.)